# Displaying collection of ("moving") markers on map, performance

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Im getting list of planes from web api with their locations and infos. Im calling this web api every few seconds and drawing the map markers (planes) to map.

When I call my method addPlanesToMap(), to add/update markers on map, map freezes for short period of time. If im movin the map at the same time the markers get added/updated there is some lag. This happens in devices like Nexus 5. There is around 200 - 300 markers in map.

Is there something how I can improve my code, do something completely differently?

```
HashMap<String, MarkerContainer> mMarkerHashMap = new HashMap <String, MarkerContainer>();

public void addPlanesToMap(List <? extends RealtimePlane > planes) {

    View planeMarkerView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_marker_plane, null);
    TextView markerShortCodeText = (TextView) planeMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.MapMarkerText);
    ImageView markerArrow = (ImageView) planeMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.MapMarkerArrow);

    for (RealtimePlane plane: planes) {
        MarkerContainer markerContainer = mMarkerHashMap.get(plane.getPlaneId());

        // Do not process, if not updated
        if (markerContainer != null && markerContainer.getPlane().getRecordedAtTime().equals(plane.getRecordedAtTime())) {
            continue;
        }

        markerShortCodeText.setText(plane.getPlaneCode());
        markerShortCodeText.setBackgroundResource(getMapMarkerDrawableBg(plane.getType()));
        markerArrow.setRotation((float) plane.getBearing());
        markerArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        // Add new plane marker to map
        if (markerContainer == null) {
            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(plane.getLocation())
                .flat(true)
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(plane.getLineCode())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(getActivity(), planeMarkerView))));

            mMarkerHashMap.put(plane.getPlaneId(), new MarkerContainer(m, plane));
        }

        // Marker already set, update
        else {
            markerContainer.getMarker().setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(getActivity(), planeMarkerView)));
            markerContainer.getMarker().setPosition(plane.getLocation());
            markerContainer.setPlane(plane);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something how I can improve my code, do something completely differently

yes, do not plot every single marker and only plot what is in the visible area. you can also do marker clustering.

Plotting 2-300 markers every few seconds is not really a good idea to begin with

Comment: Clustering is not possible in this case but drawing only those markers which are visible is of course possible. Im just wondering does this add quite lot of overhead to calculate if marker is in visible are and maybe remove those markers which are not in visible area.

Comment: well if you do the calculation in an `AsyncTask` there should be no problem